# Binding Feature is Missing in Action Panel in IIS 7.5 Manager in Window 7

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

In my workstation, I do not why the Binding ... and a few other features are missing in the Action Panel.  My Windows 2008 R2 server has all these.

[image]

I tried the control panel and could not find anything I need to turn on to make it work.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just make sure you are viewing the settings for site not application.
The binding settings are visible for site not application.